# Tithing Precision

Tags: maaser-tithes, halacha

What degree of precision is necessary when calculating *[t'rumos](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terumah)* and *[ma'asros](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maaser_Rishon)*?

The *mishnayos* deal almost exclusively with collections of discrete objects like loaves of bread and crops, but could that just be for illustrative purposes and not an indication of lesser precision?

Does the same apply (when the *Beis Hamikdash* is not standing) to tithing money?

Comment: Does tithing money stop applying when the BHM is rebuilt? Why?

Comment: @DoubleAA _Lav davka_; but what is the scope of "_kol ma d'takun rabanan_..." in this case? I might have been assuming that _ma'aser k'safim_ was a temporary replacement for the other _ma'as'ros_ because the _A"H_ uses that phrase to explain the existence of the obligation. . . every year.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Terumah Gedolah should *not* be measured with precision but should be given באומד by estimation. One should not even use a vessel of known measurement to remove the Terumah Gedolah, unless one doesn't fill the vessel to a known line. (Terumot 1:7, [Rambam Terumot 3:4](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/7303.htm#4))

Maaserot (Rishon, Sheni, Ani, and Min HaMaaser) should be given with high precision. The Mishna (Terumot 4:6) writes:

> המונה משובח והמודד משובח ממנו והשוקל משובח משלשתן.‏
>   One who counts is [more] praiseworthy [than one who estimates]; one who measures is more praiseworthy than one who counts; one who weighs is more praiseworthy than all three of them.

The Shulchan Aruch (YD 331:24) takes this as referring to a item which can be evaluated in all three ways. If it is usually only evaluated in one of the ways, then that method is sufficient.

Rambam ([Maaserot 1:14](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/7401.htm#14)) summarizes nicely:

> וכל המדקדק בשיעור משובח.‏
>   Whoever is exacting in measuring is praiseworthy.

Comment: I don't know what I was thinking when I asked the question. But I still wonder whether the precision used for actual _ma'aser_ is necessary for tithing money.

Comment: @WAF Perhaps you thought: this is a question others may have; I'll phrase it appropriately for Mi Yodeya's format.

Answer (score 2):

It seems there's something special about exactly 10%.  R S Taub, The Laws of Tzedakah and Maaser, p122, says that to fulfil "maaser" you should first isolate 10%. The first source is the third footnote Sefer Ahavat Chesed (by the Chafetz Chaim), sec 2, Ch 19, which refers to a "Sod Gadol"/"Great secret", and he also mentions a few other sources I don't recognise. I think he thinks there's something of Kabbalistic significance.

Another idea: Ethics of the Fathers 1:16 means something like "Rabban Gamliel would say 'Get a Rav and remove yourself from doubt and don't tithe approximately any more'". If it's a series of three pieces of advice then the third one might be extended to apply to money. If it's a suggestion with two pieces of justification, we are assumed to think exactness is a virtue in at least some tithes.