# Maaser Kesafim and Al Tarbeh

Tags: mishna, maaser-tithes, pirke-avot-ethicsof

There are a [variety of opinions](http://halachafortodaycom.blogspot.com/2013/02/archives-hilchos-maaser-kesafim.html) regarding the halachic status of the obligation of Maaser Kesafim. It is at least a minhag (possibly Minhag Yisroel) which may have the force of a neder for those accustomed to it, and possibly either a D'Rabannan or D'Oraisa obligation according others.

In Pirkei Avot 1:16, we are warned against using estimation as a method of separating maaser. While this would ostensibly refer to how one tithes produce (Terumot 4:6 המונה, משובח; והמודד, משובח ממנו; והשוקל, משובח משלושתן), are there opinions that apply this Mishna in Avot to the process of separating maaser Kesafim?

Comment: possible dupe http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/3043/759

Comment: That question deals explicitly with produce and physical objects, not maaser for money like we are here.

Comment: I linked to a question not an answer. Questions can't be duplicates of answers.

Comment: I don't see how this isn't exactly the same as (part of) the question @DoubleAA linked to.

Comment: @msh210 granted, the question linked adds in money, but here I'm asking if anyone connects pirkei avot to Maaser Kesafim, whereas there the OP is looking at general rules of precision for Maaser, including (possibly) money. It's a related concept, and an answer to the previous question might contain references that answer mine, but they aren't identical questions.

Comment: @IsaacKotlicky, ah! so you're asking not about the application of being exact to _maasar k'safim_ but about the application of that particular _mishna_ to _maasar k'safim_. Personally, I'd change "opinions that apply this concept" to "opinions that apply this Mishnah in Avot" in the question, then, but perhaps it's clear enough for most.

Comment: @msh210 sounds like a reasonable edit! I'll do that now...

Comment: @msh210 What does "apply this Mishnah in Avot [to MK]" mean? Certainly it wasn't intended to refer to MK as that isn't mentioned in the Mishna.

Comment: @DoubleAA On the contrary, as I linked, there are opinions which state that MK may be a d'rabannan or even a d'oraisa obligation. At the very least, it's a long standing tradition with allusions in Bereishit. It is quite possible that there are commentaries of the Mishna in Avot that interpret this as an exhortation regarding MK, or ***re***interpret the mishna to provide contemporary meaning.

Comment: @IsaacKotlicky On the contrary to what? Do you dispute that it is not mentioned in the Mishna? Whatever it's status is, the Mishna clearly isn't discussing it.

Comment: @DoubleAA but commentaries can apply the _mishna_ to it, much as _Ramban_ applied the verse _Sh'ma b'ni musar avicha_ to the letter he was writing.