# Rounding up with maasrot?

Tags: halacha

Let's say, my field produced 1009 kur of produce in the days of the Temple, when giving maaser, am I allowed to give more than 100.9 kur of produce - let's say round up to 101 kur?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not the right thing to do. Shulchan Arukh (YD 331:76) writes:

> אין מעשרין באומד אלא במדה או במשקל או במנין וכל המדקדק בשיעור משובח והמרבה במעשרות מעשרותיו מקולקלין שהרי הטבל מעורב בהן ופירותיו מתוקנין:‏
> One should not tithe through estimation but through measuring or weighing or counting, and whoever is precise in his measurement is praiseworthy, and whoever increases his tithes spoils them for untithed produce is mixed in with them and [yet] his produce is fixed.

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/3043/759